# how can I set up multiple listeners for one event?

Tags: android, composite

I want to set up multiple listeners for one event, and have found that using composite listener is the key.

Could anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
class CompositeListener implements OnEventListener {
   private List<OnEventListener> registeredListeners = new ArrayList<OnEventListener>();

   public void registerListener (OnEventListener listener) {
      registeredListeners.add(listener);
   }

   public void onEvent(Event e) {
      for(OnEventListener listener:registeredListeners) {
         listener.onEvent(e);
      }
   }
}
```

.....

```
CompositeListener composite = new CompositeListener();
composite.registerListener(listener1);
composite.registerListener(listener2);
component.setOnEventListener(composite);
```

Comment: You might want to add a remove method, since that is a part of the pattern too.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this hack
you will need to extend the view e.g. extend the Button to accept multiple onclick listeners.
you create an inner class that implements OnclickListener

```
private class OnclickListenerCollection implements OnClickListener{
    private ArrayList<OnClickListener> listeners;

    public void addOnclickListener(OnClickListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(OnClickListener l : listeners){
            l.onClick(v);
        }

    }
}
```

in the constructor of you sub-classed button, you call super.setOnclickListener passing an instance of you inner class

```
private OnclickListenerCollection listenerCollector;
```

in your constructor you have:

```
listenerCollector = new OnclickListenerCollection();
super.setOnClickListener(listenerCollector);
```

you override the setOnclickListener method to add listeners to the collection

```
@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {

    listenerCollector.addOnclickListener(l);
}
```

i have not tried it but i believe it will work

Comment: I wouldn't call this a hack.

Comment: It is a good idea. IMHO, it can be improved with one small change. As described, it alters the meaning of `setOnClickListener`.  The meaning would be clearer if instead implement two methods whose names say what they do: `addOnClickListener` and `removeOnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is several years late, but wanted to add my version that I just spent a few hours getting to work. Here is the code located in the file DBupdateEventListener.java:

```
public interface DBupdateEventListener {
    public void onUpdateChannelSubscriptions();
}
class DBupdateEventListenerRegistry implements DBupdateEventListener{
    public static List<DBupdateEventListener> registeredListeners = new ArrayList<DBupdateEventListener>();
    public void registerListener(DBupdateEventListener listener){
        registeredListeners.add(listener);
    }
    public void onUpdateChannelSubscriptions(){
        for (DBupdateEventListener listener:registeredListeners){
            listener.onUpdateChannelSubscriptions();
        }
    }
}
```

it is very VERY important that registeredListeners is a public static variable. This is the whole reason that I added my own answer to this question several years after it had already been closed.

and here is the code I use in the OnCreate() method of the fragment that needs to be updated after the event is triggered:

```
        dbUpdater = new DBupdateEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdateChannelSubscriptions() {
                //put the code you want to run when the event is triggered here:
                loadChannelListsFromDB();
            }
        };
        DBupdateEventListenerRegistry temp = new DBupdateEventListenerRegistry();
        temp.registerListener(dbUpdater);
```

and here is the code used in my asynchronous task that triggers the event in the first place:

```
dbUpdaterRegistry = new DBupdateEventListenerRegistry();
dbUpdaterRegistry.onUpdateChannelSubscriptions();
```

Comment: `registeredListeners` only needs to be `static` if it isn't a field on an object that is already known to be staying around for as long as is needed. One downside of `static` is that now it will stay around for as long as your app is alive. While sometimes that is good, it isn't a "recipe" that you want to be in the habit of using. A second downside of `static` is that now you can't create **two instances** of the class, each with their own set of listeners.  Instead, in an activity/fragment, have a **field** `DBupdateEventListenerRegistry eventRegistry;`, for the listeners of that activity.