# Andorid : setOnClickListener does not work when calling Twice

Tags: java, android

I'm using `setOnClickListener`  for listening on the click event on `imageButton` in two methods, but it's does not fire in my another method,my first listener firing but my second listener does not fire please see my codes :

```
Class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        this.methodA();
        this.methodB();
    }
    public void methodA()
    {
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) RContextHelper.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_location_button);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //event firing when image button touched
            }
        });
    }

    public void methodB()
    {
        Test test = new Test(this);
        test.methodA();
    }
}
class Test
{
    Context con;
    public Test(Context con)
    {
        this.con = con;
    }
    public void methodA()
    {
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_location_button);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //event does not fire when image button touched
            }
        });
    }
    protected ActionBarActivity getActivity()
    {
        return (ActionBarActivity) con;
    }
}
```

Comment: please Post Related code from where you r calling these Classes

Comment: this code calling from activity

Comment: please Explain this line :     ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) (ActionBarActivity) con.findViewById(R.id.my_location_button);

Comment: why ActionBarActivity here

Comment: Let me update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can guess from the name `setOnClickListener` **sets** the new listener and **replaces** the old one. That is the case with all the `set*` listeners in Java. If it was `addOnClickListener` then you could expect that both `listeners` should be called.

If you want both of them to be called, you can write a composite on click listener and add both of the listeners to it and set the **composite** listener to the target.

```
class CompositeListener implements OnEventListener {
   private List<OnEventListener> registeredListeners = new ArrayList<OnEventListener>();

   public void registerListener (OnEventListener listener) {
      registeredListeners.add(listener);
   }

   public void onEvent(Event e) {
      for(OnEventListener listener:registeredListeners) {
         listener.onEvent(e);
      }
   }
}
```

And then:

```
CompositeListener composite = new CompositeListener();
composite.registerListener(listener1);
composite.registerListener(listener2);
imageButton.setOnEventListener(composite);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465204/how-can-i-set-up-multiple-listeners-for-one-event)

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing to code with two `methodA` functions. You never call the second one. At least you are not showing code for that. Moreover - as has been said already - there can only be one listener.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry. It was ment as comment of course. I blame the confusing layout/design of the mobile version of this page.